# Accessing params in Rails Policy Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Update**

I've tried __adding another sql query for `:specific_trainees`, but doing this and calling `UNION` on the two SQL queries will simply share the resource with al trainees regardless if I select `:all_trainees` or  `:specific_trainees`.

I'm curious if it's possible to access the params object within a Rails PolicyObject.

Below, I have a scope class in the policy

```
class ResourcePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    true
  end

  alias :new? :index?
  alias :create? :index?

  def destroy?
    record.resource_duty == user
  end

  class Scope < ApplicationPolicy::Scope
    def resolve
      employee_resources = scope.left_outer_joins(:resource_roles, :resource_locations).where(
        '
          resource_duty_id IN(?)
          AND (permitted_employees = ? OR resource_roles.job_role_id IN(?))
          AND (permitted_locations = ? OR resource_locations.location_id IN(?))
        ',
        user.organization_ids,
        Resource.permitted_employees[:all_employees], user.job_role_ids,
        Resource.permitted_locations[:all_locations], user.location_ids
      ).where(namespace: 'company')

      all_trainees_resources = scope.left_outer_joins(:resource_courses).where(
        'resource_duty_id IN(?) AND (permitted_trainees = ? OR resource_courses.course_id IN(?))',
        user.training_organization_ids,
        Resource.permitted_trainees[:all_trainees],
        user.cards.pluck(:course_id)
      ).where(namespace: 'training_provider')

      specific_trainees_resources = scope.left_outer_joins(:resource_courses).where(
        'resource_duty_id IN(?) AND (permitted_trainees = ? OR resource_courses.course_id IN(?))',
        user.training_organization_ids,
        Resource.permitted_trainees[:specific_trainees],
        user.cards.pluck(:course_id)
      ).where(namespace: 'training_provider')

      cardholder_resources = scope.where(resource_duty: user)

      # NOTE: this is all a bit hackey. It might be worth using the sequel gem to improve this
      sql = Resource.connection.unprepared_statement {
        "((#{employee_resources.to_sql}) UNION (#{all_trainees_resources.to_sql}) UNION (#{specific_trainees_resources.to_sql}) UNION (#{cardholder_resources.to_sql})) AS resources"
      }

      Resource.from(sql)
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to change **`Resource.permitted_trainees[:all_trainees]`** to **`Resource.permitted_trainees[:specific_trainees]`** based on the parameters passed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `params` are a controller value. I'm assuming this is Pundit, although you don't specify (you should). If you're using Pundit which really only takes a user and the model, you may need something like https://github.com/varvet/pundit#user-content-additional-context, but... this is a workaround.

Comment: Yeah @DaveNewton, I was thinking the same, but was curious to know if there was a work-around.  I'm working on a possible solution right now.

Comment: This *is* the workaround. It's not clear to me from the example whether or not this is just a query difference, in which case the policy isn't involved at all.

Comment: Okay...my solution didn't work...
The policy does a PSQL query joining some tables together, to share that resource with a specific user/trainee

Heres the union of the tables


`sql = Resource.connection.unprepared_statement {
        "((#{employee_resources.to_sql}) UNION (#{trainee_resources.to_sql}) UNION (#{cardholder_resources.to_sql})) AS resources"
      }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that when you say "Rails PolicyObject", you mean "Pundit Policy" and not a homegrown solution that you're using.

That said, it is possible, though not recommended by the Pundit team.

See [this section of the docs](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#additional-context), which essentially recommends doing something like this:

```rb
class UserContext
  attr_reader :user, :show_all_trainees

  def initialize(user, show_all_trainees)
    @user = user
    @show_all_trainees   = show_all_trainees
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  include Pundit

  def pundit_user
    UserContext.new(current_user, request.show_all_trainees)
  end
end
```

That more direct answer given to your question, I think the better approach is not to pass in a parameter, but to use the `User` object or the `Trainee` policy that you should already have  in order to determine which Trainees are displayed.

You could do something like:

```rb
trainee_resources = scope.left_outer_joins(:resource_courses).where(
    'resource_duty_id IN(?) AND (permitted_trainees = ? OR resource_courses.course_id IN(?))',
    user.training_organization_ids,
    policy_scope(Trainee),
    user.cards.pluck(:course_id)
  ).where(namespace: 'training_provider')
```

You could also do a simple `if` statement around the variable definition based on something like the `User` role or other attribute that signals which Trainees they should have access to.

Without more information about your Application architecture it's hard to be too much more specific, but hopefully one of those routes leads you to the solution you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks @s_dolan!

I think I've got a solution I'm working on, now.
Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Hey @s_dolan, I've updated my original post.  My solution didn't work in the end...

Comment: I’m still not sure why either of the approaches I’ve provided won’t work for you. Do you not have some way, based on the user record, to determine which trainees should be loaded?

Comment: Hey @s_dolan, I've tried your 2nd suggestion and it doesn't work, unfortunately...
I'm working with a fairly large code base that's been handed down, so I'm still trying to fully understand everything.